# How does softmax work for vectors?

Tags: word-embeddings, softmax, word2vec

In skipgram we predict the context words. That is the output layer before applying the softmax function is a number $V$ of words, where $V$ is the dictionary size. But each word is represented as a vector. So we have $V$ vectors in the output layer. And now we want to apply softmax to those vectors to get a vector of dimensionality $V$, where each component represents the probability of a word appearing with an input word. But how do we apply the softmax function to vectors? By definition the softmax function takes as input a single vector, but we have $V$ vectors each of a chosen dimensionality $N$.